# how to delete duplicate rows from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1093

I need to delete duplicate record from table in mysql.
So i have a table name "employee" fields are empid, empname, empssn

for getting duplicate record i have written a query

```
SELECT COUNT(empssn), empssn FROM employee 
GROUP BY empssn 
HAVING COUNT(empssn) > 1
```

Now I want to delete duplicate records. For that I have written query is.

```
DELETE FROM employee 
WHERE (empid, empssn) NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(empid), empssn FROM employee 
    GROUP BY empssn
);
```

you can assume records in table are

```
EmpId  EmpName  EmpSSN
-------------------------------
 1     Jack     555-55-5555
 2     Joe      555-56-5555
 3     Fred     555-57-5555
 4     Mike     555-58-5555
 5     Cathy    555-59-5555
 6     Lisa     555-70-5555
 7     Jack     555-55-5555
 8     Mike     555-58-5555
 9     Cathy    555-59-5555
10     Lisa     555-70-5555
11     Lisa     555-70-5555
```

but I have a mysql error is

> You can't specify target table 'employee' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 10):

Does the trick of wrapping it into a derived table work for this case? (Based on http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)

```
DELETE FROM employee 
WHERE (empid, empssn) NOT IN (
    SELECT empid, empssn FROM (
        SELECT MIN(empid) AS empid, empssn FROM employee 
        GROUP BY empssn
    ) X
);
```

**Edit** Yep it seems to work this end.