# Remove duplicates using only a MySQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
URL_ID    
URL_ADDR    
URL_Time
```

I want to remove duplicates on the `URL_ADDR` column using a MySQL query.

Is it possible to do such a thing without using any programming?

Comment: SQL is programming...

Comment: How does the URLs in URL_ADDR looks like? Do they all have the same format? i.e: with or without www.

Answer (score 38):

Consider the following test case:

```
CREATE TABLE mytb (url_id int, url_addr varchar(100));

INSERT INTO mytb VALUES (1, 'www.google.com');
INSERT INTO mytb VALUES (2, 'www.microsoft.com');
INSERT INTO mytb VALUES (3, 'www.apple.com');
INSERT INTO mytb VALUES (4, 'www.google.com');
INSERT INTO mytb VALUES (5, 'www.cnn.com');
INSERT INTO mytb VALUES (6, 'www.apple.com');
```

Where our test table now contains:

```
SELECT * FROM mytb;
+--------+-------------------+
| url_id | url_addr          |
+--------+-------------------+
|      1 | www.google.com    |
|      2 | www.microsoft.com |
|      3 | www.apple.com     |
|      4 | www.google.com    |
|      5 | www.cnn.com       |
|      6 | www.apple.com     |
+--------+-------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then we can use the multiple-table [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) syntax as follows:

```
DELETE t2
FROM   mytb t1
JOIN   mytb t2 ON (t2.url_addr = t1.url_addr AND t2.url_id > t1.url_id);
```

... which will delete duplicate entries, leaving only the first url based on `url_id`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytb;
+--------+-------------------+
| url_id | url_addr          |
+--------+-------------------+
|      1 | www.google.com    |
|      2 | www.microsoft.com |
|      3 | www.apple.com     |
|      5 | www.cnn.com       |
+--------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**UPDATE** - Further to new comments above:

If the duplicate URLs will not have the same format, you may want to apply the [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to remove `www.` or `http://` parts. For example:

```
DELETE t2
FROM   mytb t1
JOIN   mytb t2 ON (REPLACE(t2.url_addr, 'www.', '') = 
                   REPLACE(t1.url_addr, 'www.', '') AND 
                   t2.url_id > t1.url_id);
```

Comment: So, a JOIN won't trigger the 1093 error?  Granted, a JOIN isn't a subquery but being self-referential is the real issue....

Comment: @OMG: It looks like it doesn't :)

Comment: @OMG Poines: RE the 1093 error, I also tried an `UPDATE` using a self-referential `JOIN` and another using a subquery that selects from the same table. The `JOIN`
 test succeeds while the subquery one fails with the 1093 error. The same seems to happen for `DELETE`.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to try the method mentioned at http://labs.creativecommons.org/2010/01/12/removing-duplicate-rows-in-mysql/.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX `tmp_index` (URL_ADDR);
```

Comment: `ALTER IGNORE` is no longer supported as of MySQL 5.7.4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5456599/1924128

Answer (score 5):

This will leave the ones with the highest `URL_ID` for a particular `URL_ADDR`

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE URL_ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT ID FROM 
       (SELECT MAX(URL_ID) AS ID 
        FROM table 
        WHERE URL_ID IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY URL_ADDR ) X)   /*Sounds like you would need to GROUP BY a 
                                   calculated form - e.g. using REPLACE to 
                                  strip out www see Daniel's answer*/
```

(The derived table 'X' is to [avoid the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271396/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-table-in-mysql/3271407#3271407) "You can't specify target table 'tablename' for update in FROM clause")

Comment: @Vilx: That's why you bury it in a another subquery.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could always:

1. create a temporary table;
2. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT DISTINCT` into the temp table from original table;
3. clear original table
4. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` into the original table from the temp table
5. drop temp table.

It's clumsy and awkward, and requires several queries (not to mention privileges), but it will do the trick if you don't find another solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by on the URL_ADDR which will effectively give you only distinct values in the URL_ADDR field.

```
select 
 URL_ID
 URL_ADDR
 URL_Time
from
 some_table
group by
 URL_ADDR
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Vassallo How to for multiple column?

`DELETE t2
FROM directory1 t1
JOIN directory1 t2 ON
   (t2.page = t1.page,
    t2.parentTopic = t1.parentTopic,
    t2.title = t1.title,
    t2.description = t1.description,
    t2.linktype = t1.linktype,
    t2.priority = t1.priority
    AND t2.linkID > t1.linkID);`

maybe like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 DELETE FROM `your_table`
 WHERE 
    `unique_id` IN (
    SELECT 
        `unique_id`
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            `unique_id_in_table`,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY `group_by_column`
                ORDER BY `group_by_column`) AS row_num
        FROM 
            `your_table`
    ) t
     WHERE row_num > 1
 );
```

Where:

- your_table is table name
- group_by_column is column you want to be unique
- unique_id_in_table is id which should be unique for each row

Answer (score 0):

This will work provided that your URL_ID column is unique.

```
DELETE FROM url WHERE URL_ID IN (
SELECT URL_ID
FROM url a INNER JOIN (
    SELECT URL_ADDR, MAX(URL_ID) MaxURLId 
    FROM url
    GROUP BY URL_ADDR
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b ON a.URL_ID <> b.MaxURLId AND a.URL_ADDR = b.URL_ADDR
)
```