# how to delete duplicate entry by one SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

i has a table `deal`:

```
CREATE TABLE `deal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `site` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `area` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

i want to create :

```
UNIQUE KEY `site` (`site`,`area`,`name`);
```

but now, `name` filed is not UNIQUE,when i create this key,i get error:

```
duplicate entry 'aaa' for key 2
```

my table datas:

```
Data
id site  area  name
---------------------------------
1  site1 area1 aaa
2  site1 area2 bbb
3  site1 area1 aaa   <<<< i want delete this
4  site2 area1 ccc
5  site2 area1 ccc   <<<< i want delete this
...
```

how to do it by one sql string?

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer from this link Hope should help you - Since you already have ID column, ignore the adding of identity in my answer

[deleting duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385661/deleting-duplicate-records/3386958#3386958)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it for you

```
Delete From deal
Where ID in (

    Select Max(Id)
    From deal
    Group by [site], area, [Name]
    Having Count(id) > 1
        )
```

As this is a Delete - This is untested so please test it first.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM site
      WHERE id NOT IN (
              SELECT id
                FROM site
            GROUP BY name
            )
```