# How to remove duplicates from a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicates using only a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383898/remove-duplicates-using-only-a-mysql-query)

I have a table with different pages but some of them are duplicates. The only way to determine duplicates are by title. I run the code below and it works perfectly:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("old") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pagetitle, COUNT( * ) c
FROM cms_site_content
GROUP BY pagetitle
HAVING c >1") or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id'].'-'.$row['pagetitle'].'<br />';
}

?>
```

My question is: How can I erase duplicates and keep only one entry. For example if I have an article called "Duplicate Article" and the result is

> Duplicate Article: 3

I want to keep only one.

Comment: hi andrei, can you post the schema of your table and sample records? thanks. it helps a lot when asking question :)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for **new** code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Isn't this something you can do by hand on the database table? If not, what's the criteria for deleting a duplicate page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to `INNER JOIN` the table on itself and delete where the `pagetitle` values are identical but the `primary key` (I'm using ID as the identifier) is not.

Try:

```
DELETE c2 FROM `cms_site_content` c1 INNER JOIN
               `cms_site_content` c2
          ON c1.pagetitle = c2.pagetitle AND c1.ID <> c2.ID
```

**Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Also reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3383920/62671

Comment: I've used this code:  <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("old") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'cms_site_content' AS c1 INNER JOIN 'cms_site_content' AS c2 ON m1.pagetitle = m2.pagetitle AND c1.id <> c2.id") or die(mysql_error());  

?>  and it gives me: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM 'cms_site_content' AS c1 INNER JOIN 'cms_site_content' AS c2 ON m1.pageti' at line 1

Comment: I've used this: DELETE FROM 'cms_site_content' AS c1 INNER JOIN 'cms_site_content' AS c2 ON m1.pagetitle = m2.pagetitle AND c1.id <> c2.id (without an *). Got this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS c1 INNER JOIN cms_site_content AS c2 ON m1.pagetitle = m2.pagetitle AND c1.id' at line 1

Comment: '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c1 INNER JOIN cms_site_content c2 ON c1.pagetitle = c2.pagetitle AND c1.ID &lt;&gt; c2' at line 1' - This was made directly in phpMyAdmin

Comment: DELETE c2 FROM... was the right code :)

Answer (score 0):

Select all single rows, insert them into a temp table, delete all record, insert them back from temp

Use some application logic: select only one from each multiple row, delete all from the table, then insert back the single ones

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
SELECT DISTINCT pagetitle, id, FROM cms_site_content

Save all ids to idlist use PHP from above SQL and then execute:

DELETE FROM cms_site_content WHERE id NOT in ($idlist)

You need to translate above SQL statements to PHP/MySQL code.

Comment: You can do this without PHP in pure SQL.

Comment: Yes, the other posts are simpler

Answer (score 0):

This line woked:

```
DELETE t2
FROM cms_site_content t1
JOIN cms_site_content t2 ON (t2.pagetitle = t1.pagetitle AND t2.id > t1.id);
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name
```