# How add unique key to existing table (with non uniques rows)

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms, unique-key

I want to add complex unique key to existing table. Key contains from 4 fields (`user_id`, `game_id`, `date`, `time`).
But table have non unique rows.
I understand that I can remove all duplicate dates and after that add complex key.

Maybe exist another solution without searching all duplicate data. (like add unique ignore etc).

UPD
I searched, how can remove duplicate mysql rows - i think it's good solution.
[Remove duplicates using only a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383898/remove-duplicates-using-only-a-mysql-query)

Comment: You can't have duplicates if you create a unique key.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can do as yAnTar advised

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

OR

You can add a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD CONSTRAINT constr_ID UNIQUE (user_id, game_id, date, time)
```

But I think to not lose your existing data, you can add an indentity column and then make a composite key.

Comment: what is an IDENTITY column ? I can find no reference of it in the doc except something related to AUTO_INCREMENT : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: As mentioned by @challet the key word in MySQL is NOT IDENTITY but AUTO_INCREMENT.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: For clarity the mysql syntax is:
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Comment: The OP did not (explicitly) specify a particular database. IDENTITY is the correct syntax for MS/Oracle SQL-Server and perhaps other non MySQL/MariaDB dialects, for them use the AUTO_INCREMENT syntax .

Comment: The question is tagged with 'mysql', so the solution should apply to that DBMS

Answer (score 34):

The proper syntax would be - `ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD UNIQUE (column_name)`

> Example

```
ALTER TABLE  0_value_addition_setup ADD UNIQUE (`value_code`)
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This marks the column unique if there are no duplicate entries. If there are some, it errors in `Duplicate entry 'my_value' for key 'my_key' `

Comment: This is not 100 percent correct syntax as per MySQL web site

Answer (score 11):

I had to solve a similar problem. I inherited a large source table from MS Access with nearly 15000 records that did not have a primary key, which I had to normalize and make CakePHP compatible. One convention of CakePHP is that every table has a the primary key, that it is first column and that it is called 'id'. The following simple statement did the trick for me under MySQL 5.5:

```
ALTER TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` 
ADD COLUMN `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

This added a new column 'id' of type integer in front of the existing data ("FIRST" keyword). The AUTO_INCREMENT keyword increments the ids starting with 1. Now every dataset has a unique numerical id. (Without the AUTO_INCREMENT statement all rows are populated with id = 0).

Answer (score 3):

I am providing my solution with the assumption on your business logic. Basically in my design I will allow the table to store only one record for a user-game combination.  So I will add a composite key to the table.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`game_id`)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Set Multiple Unique key into table

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_table_name UNIQUE (field1,field2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either create an auto-increment id or a UNIQUE id and add it to the natural key you are talking about with the 4 fields. this will make every row in the table unique...

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

If yourColumnName has some values doesn't unique, and now you wanna add an unique index for it. Try this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IDX_Name] ON yourTableName (yourColumnName) WHERE [id]>1963 --1963 is max(id)-1
```

Now, try to insert some values are exists for test.