# Delete MySQL row from PHP while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop displaying my database columns and rows in table.

I want make a button which can delete specific MySQL row but unfortunately I can't select which of all rows have to be deleted simply because I use "while loop" to display my database content in HTML.

Providing picture for better understanding what I want to do:
[image]

So yeah, I want that when the green button is clicked - send MySQL query to delete this row (which is existing in my DB).

Providing code:

```
<?php
//CONECT TO MYSQL
include 'database.php';

//GET VALUES
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM amountcontainer";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);


        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {
            //Table headlines - NOT A PHP
            echo "<table class='moneytable'>
                    <tr>
                        <th style='background-color: #2d323a; color: white;'>Date</th>
                        <th style='background-color: #2d323a; color: white;'>Amount</th>
                        <th style='background-color: #2d323a; color: white;'>Reason</th>
                    </tr>";

            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {

                //RED //Make statement of amount red if it has a " - "
                if(strpos($row['amount'],'-') !== false)
                {

                    echo 
                    "
                        <tr>
                            <th style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-time'>" . $row['time'] . "</th>
                            <th style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-amount'>" . $row['amount'] . "</th>
                            <th style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-reason'>" . $row['reason'] . "</th>
                        </tr>

                    ";

                }

                //NORMAL //Make statement of amount normal if it doesn't have a " - "
                else
                {
                    echo 
                    "
                        <tr>
                            <th style='font-weight: normal;' class='row-time'>" . $row['time'] . "</th>
                            <th style='font-weight: normal;' class='row-amount'>" . $row['amount'] . "</th>
                            <th style='font-weight: normal;' class='row-reason'>" . $row['reason'] . "</th>
                        </tr>

                    ";

                }


            }
            echo "</table>";
        } 

        else 
        {
            echo "0 results";
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a primary index or unique key on the table that you can reference to delete the row?

Comment: I don't have. I was thinking to do the same but can't figure out how.

Comment: [Have a look here, friend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255304/how-add-unique-key-to-existing-table-with-non-uniques-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, only use `<th>` elements for the table headers.  For the actual data cells use the `<td>` element.

To allow deletion of individual database rows you can include links in your table.  In your loop that creates the table rows:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['reason'] . "</td>
                        <td><a href='?deleteId=$row[keyID]'>Delete</a></td> 
                    </tr>
```

In this case, when the "Delete" link is selected it calls your same script with a $_GET variable: "deleteId" which you can test for and if found, perform the delete of the row.  You can also embed the table in an html form and add a submit button to a cell in each row, with the value of the submit set to the row id to delete.

Comment: As @Ohgodwhy mentioned you will need a primary key for the table.  Almost without exception every table in your database should have a primary key.

Comment: I think this might be the answer. How can I call function with this "GET" method though? I just tested it and I see it marks my row, which is great!

Comment: In the example the primary key of the table is "keyID" in your table you will need to have column that represents the unique identifier of a row in your table.  When you click the link it will call the same page but with a url parameter.  You can test for it like:  if($_GET['deletedId']) { $sql = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE keyID = '$_GET[deletedId]' ";

Comment: Also FYI use prepared statements or at least mysqli_real_escape_string on the $_GET variable before using it in the delete statement to prevent SQL-Injection.  Good luck!

Comment: It says "Notice: Undefined index: deleteId" when I put this on the code.
EDIT: I have mistake , sorry. Will tell you what's going on tho!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a place for ajax. Heres a crude example that might give you a good starting point.

```
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $isNegative = strpos($row['amount'],'-') !== false;

    echo "<tr class='record' data-id=\"{$row["id"]}\">";
    //Use ternary operator & css classes
    echo "<td class='standard-record ".$isNegative ? "color-red" : "" ."''>{$row["record"]}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
<script>
    $(".record").click(function(){
        var request = {
            id: $(this).data("id")
        };
        $.post( "delete-record.php", request, function(data){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
if(strpos($row['amount'],'-') !== false) # wrong way
```

to this

```
if($row['amount'] < 0) # detecting negative numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra

```
<th style='font-weight: normal;' class='row-reason'><a class="crossBtn" href="?del_id=".$row['id'].">&nbsp;</a></th>
```

And the get the del_id and delete this specific records.