# How to delete specific row of while loop with delete button in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

I have a while loop displaying my database columns and rows in the table.

I want to make a button which can delete specific MySQL row but unfortunately, I can't select which of all rows have to be deleted simply because I use "while loop" to display my database content in HTML.

```
    <?php
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","done");
    if(isset($_POST['deletesubmit'])){
    $deleteId=$_POST['deleteId'];
    $query3="DELETE FROM dones WHERE  id=deleteId";
    $result3=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    }
    ?>


   <?php

    $query="SELECT * FROM dones where id>3";
    $result1=mysqli_query($db,$query);

   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
   {

   echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';
   echo '<div class="card" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">';
   echo '<div class="card-header">';
     echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
     echo '<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
   style="height:430px;">';
      echo  '<button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration:none; font- 
   family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:18px; " type="button" 
   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" 
   aria-controls="collapseOne">';
      echo   $row['title'];

       echo '</button>';
      echo '</h5>';
    echo '</div>';

   echo '<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria- 
   labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">';
   echo  '<div class="card-body">';

   // Content Of new banner


   echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;"> 
   <small>Title</small></h5>';
   echo '<input style="width:290px; margin-left:158px; height:30px; margin- 
   top:-30px;" name="title" type="text" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="Title">';
   echo ' <br>';
   echo ' <div class="custom-file" style="height:10px; width:290px; margin- 
   right:1050px; top-padding:20px; float:right;">';
   echo ' <input type="file" name="uploadfile" class="custom-file-input" 
   id="validatedCustomFile">';
   echo ' <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choose 
   file...</label>';
   echo ' </div>';
   echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>File</small> 
   </h5>';
   echo ' <br>';
   echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>Banner 
   Image</small></h5>';
   echo ' <div style="height:130px; width:290px; border-width:1px; border- 
   style:solid; float:right; margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-15px;">';


     $sql="SELECT image FROM dones where status=1";
     $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
     $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     echo '<img src= "images/'.$data['image'].'" style="height:130px; 
     width:290px;">';

     echo '</div>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';  
     echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"> 
     <small>Status</small></h5>';
     echo '<select name="status" id="" style="width:290px; float:right; 
     margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-25px;">';
     echo '<option value="1" name="enable">Enable</option>';
     echo '<option value="0" name="disable">Disable</option>';
     echo '</select>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<button type="submit" name="tbsubmit"  style="margin-left:250px;" 
     class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>';  
     echo  '<a name="deleteId" href="?deleteId=$row[keyID]"></a>';
     echo '<button type="submit" name="deletesubmit"  style="margin- 
     left:250px;"  class="btn btn-primary">Delete Banner</button>'; 
     echo '</div>';

     echo '</form>';
     echo '</div>';



    echo  '</div>';
   echo '</div>';
   echo '</div>';
   echo '</div>';

    }    

   ?>
```

So any idea to solve the problem.

Comment: This could help you: [Delete MySQL row from PHP while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057653/delete-mysql-row-from-php-while-loop)

Comment: Dear you are using  query string to pass row id echo  '<a name="deleteId" href="?deleteId=$row[keyID]"></a>';  so dony use submit buttion <a> tag is sufficent to pass Id. i am recommend use seprate page delete.php. echo  '<a name="deleteId" href="delete.php?deleteId=$row[keyID]"></a>'; <?php
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","done");
    if(isset($_GET['deleteId'])){
    $deleteId=$_GET['deleteId'];
    $query3="DELETE FROM dones WHERE  id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($deleteId,$db)."'";
    $result3=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    }
    ?>

Comment: What changes I must bring in this page without creating another page

Comment: you also made here mistake $query3="DELETE FROM dones WHERE  id=deleteId"; instead of $query3="DELETE FROM dones WHERE  id=" .$deleteId ."; and I didn't read your full code.

Answer (score 0):

````
```
<?php
include 'config.php';//connection
?>

<?php
$sql = "select * from tablename";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($num > 0)
{ 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$id=$row[0];
$title=$row[1];
$info=$row[2];
?>


<tr>
<td><?php echo $title;?></td>
<td><?php echo $info; ?></td>
<td><form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" hidden="true">
<button type="submit" name="dlt">Delete</button>
</form></td>
</tr>



<?php
}
}
if(isset($_POST['dlt']))
{
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value)
{
$id=$value;
}
$query = "delete from tablename where id='".$id."'";
if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
echo "<script>
alert('row Deleted..');
</script>";
}
}
?>
````