# how to check if user is logged in database C#

Tags: c#, sql

```
    void checkOnline()
    {
        string sql = "select * from png_users where username = '" + txtboxUsername.Text + "' and password = '"  + txtboxPassword.Text + "' and userstatus = '1'";
        cm = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn);
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This account is currently online, you forgot to logout. Please approach administrator for help. Thank you", "THD FAM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            dr.Close();
            this.Close();
            return;
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty new to database and I am trying to figure out how to use sessions to check and see if a user is logged into a database so that they would have authorization to access specific pages.

Thanks For Help

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Learning purpose? Because it shouldn't be a problem to log in again, if a user forgot to log out.
What is not working with your posted code?
Another hint: add [using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to your disposable classes, that way you dont have to care about disposing it yourself.

Comment: ASP.Net Webforms?  MVC? What are you doing for a session cookie? Please [edit] your question for more details.

Comment: Which .net Framework are you using

Comment: This code is wrong, it is utterly insecure. SQL Injection, wrong password policy

Comment: It's a challenge for me, I got no idea how to do if user login the other people can't access that account because someone already logged in

Answer (score 3):

According to *comments*

> If the `userstatus` is `0` you can use the account and if the
>   `userstatus = 1` you can't access the account because someone already
>   used it

we should check for `3` cases:

- user / password not found (let's return `-1` as `userstatus` for this)
- user owns the account (`userstatus` is `0`)
- account belongs to some other user (`userstatus` is `1`)

Let's *extract method*:

```
  // -1 Account does't exist 
  //  0 Account exists and belongs to the user
  //  1 Account exists and belongs to different user
  public int UserLogStatus(string login, string password) {
    //DONE: do not reuse connection, but create a new one
    using (var con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
      con.Open();

      //DONE: keep sql readable
      //DONE: make sql parametrized 
      string sql = 
        @"select userstatus
            from png_users 
           where username = @prm_username and
                 password = @prm_password";  

      //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using 
      using (MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand(sql, con)) {
        //TODO: better create params explicitly, Parameters.Add(name, type).Value = ...
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_username", login);
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_password", pasword);

        using (var reader = query.ExecuteReader()) {
          if (reader.Read()) 
            return Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
          else
            return -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And then you can use it:

```
  int status = IsUserLogged(txtboxUsername.Text, txtboxPassword.Text);

  if (status == 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("Either username or password is incorrect.", 
                    "THD FAM", 
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                     MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    return;
  } 
  else if (status == 1) {
    MessageBox.Show("This account is currently online, you forgot to logout. Please approach administrator for help. Thank you", 
                    "THD FAM", 
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                     MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    return;
  }
```

**Warning!** Do not store passwords as *plain text*. If someone steal the table all the users will be compromised. Store *password hashes* instead. When logging on, user must provide a string (`password`), such that

```
  HashFunction(password) == StoredHash
```

where `HashFunction` is *one way function*: easy to compute (i.e. it's easy to find `HashFunction(password)` value), difficult to *reverse* (i.e. it's almost impossible to find a sting such that `HashFunction(password) == given value`)

Comment: Mr. Bychenko ftw! I really hope your are teaching people offline too ;-)

Comment: If the userstatus is = 0 you can use the account and if the userstatus = 1 you can't access the account because someone already used it

Comment: @Anden Castillo: Do you want to return `userstatus`? Say, `0` - user owns the acount, `1` - account exists but it belongs to a different user, `-1` - account doesn't exist.

Comment: when i use my account in database the userstatus in my row will be 1 and if the application is exit userstatus in database in my row will be 0

Comment: @Anden Castillo: technically if you want to change the status you can try using `update png_users set userstatus = @prm_userstatus where username = @prm_username and password = @prm_password` query; however, I doubt if two different users can share same `username` *and* `password`. I think you can declare `username` with `unique constraint` and just do not allow users have same names.

Comment: can you give me codes so i can get some idea :) thank you for help btw i appreciate it

Comment: @Anden Castillo: to add `unique` constraint (`alter table`) if you don't want to allow users share same name or name + password combination:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255304/how-add-unique-key-to-existing-table-with-non-uniques-rows

Answer (score -2):

You have to close the connection with con.close();