# MySQL remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table of the form:

```
NAME |    DATE    | INFO  | SPEC
Bob  | 01.01.2010 | Text1 | Student
Ann  | 02.02.2020 | Text2 | Secretary
Bob  | 01.01.2010 | Text1 | Student
John | 03.03.2030 | Text3 | Tester
Bob  | 01.01.2010 | Text1 | Student
```

How can I get a table (in request) like this:

```
NAME |    DATE    | INFO  | SPEC
Bob  | 01.01.2010 | Text1 | Student
Ann  | 02.02.2020 | Text2 | Secretary
John | 03.03.2030 | Text3 | Tester
```

PS: These variants aren't working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Date, Info, Spec FROM Table
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table
SELECT Name, Date, Info, Spec FROM Table GROUP BY Name, Date, Info, Spec
SELECT * FROM Table GROUP BY Name, Date, Info, Spec
```

Comment: Consider using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383898/remove-duplicates-using-only-a-mysql-query

Comment: Is there any primary key, other than these columns?

Comment: @All answers, Title says, user wants to delete duplicate rows, not only select.

Comment: @user3505828 do your table has more columns?, please share table schema.

Comment: The table has no primary key and no more collums

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword

Try a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MyTable
```

However, you would be better off getting rid of duplicates in your table. See [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql) to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT`. [From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> The ALL and DISTINCT options specify whether duplicate rows should be returned. ALL (the default) specifies that all matching rows should be returned, including duplicates. DISTINCT 
>   specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

So use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is Primary key other than mentioned columns, then you can use this code,

```
delete from myTable where pkID not in
(
select min(pkID) from myTable
group by NAME,DATE ,INFO ,SPEC
)
```

Assuming that **pkID** is primary key

If there is no other column than these 4 columns, then do it in following way, Using Temp Tables.

```
Create table #tmp
(
    NAME varchar(50),
    DATE date,
    INFO varchar(50),
    SPEC varchar(50)
)
insert into #tmp
select distinct * from myTable


delete from myTable

insert into myTable
    select * from #tmp
```

Code is of SQL Server, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DISTINCT` in your select query