# MySQL - Delete rows from a table where columns duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to delete duplicate rows from a table in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271396/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-table-in-mysql)

I have a simple request which is becoming a nightmare.

I have a table 'MyTableA' with two columns ID(int) and Value(varchar(100))

The table has some values like so:

```
ID|Value
1|Apple
2|Apple
3|Apple
```

Wherever Value is a duplicate I want to keep the first ID row and delete the rest of the rows.  So in the above example i want to delete rows with the ID 2 and 3.

I assumed this was simple but it might be because i'm using to SQL having clauses.

Thanks!

Comment: @Asad really it's not I kept the example simple the real issue is that it's not a 3 row table but more along the line sof a 50k row table with about 100 lines

Comment: The same solution could be applied though, couldn't it? Did you try the approach suggested?

Comment: I'm not sure how the number of rows in the table even remotely relates to whether or not this is a duplicate question.  You are asking very simply:  "How do I delete duplicated data in a MySQL table" which is very clearly answered by Asad's linked post.

Comment: As outlined in Asad's linked duplicate question, one approach for this would be to create a temp table with the data you'd like to delete, then inner join that table back to delete the targeted rows.  Other approaches exist as well.

This is a problem you'll want to understand for a lot of reasons, not the least of which being that its an extremely common interview question.

Answer (score 5):

Try...

```
DELETE t FROM `dbtable` t
  JOIN `dbtable` t2 ON t.`Value` = t2.`Value`
WHERE t.`ID` > t2.`ID`
```

Comment: Just sits and spins on the query

Answer (score 0):

you can possible delete it by joining the table with a subquery (*the subquery gets the minimum ID per value*)

```
DELETE a FROM tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT Value, MIN(ID) minID
          FROM tableName
          GROUP BY Value
        ) b ON a.ID = b.minID
WHERE  b.minID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73483/1)