# #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql

I have this problem while trying to select and delete. Can you guys help me to get this worked ?

```
SELECT `danyel_site`.`server_week`.* FROM `server_week` WHERE `weekly` = 0 AND `time` NOT IN (SELECT * FROM `server_week` WHERE `weekly` = 0 ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10)
```

I also want to use delete

```
DELETE FROM `server_week` WHERE `weekly` = 0 AND `time` NOT IN (SELECT * FROM `server_week` WHERE `weekly` = 0 ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Answer (score 19):

you can do it with a subquery like that

```
DELETE FROM `server_week` WHERE `weekly` = 0 AND `time` NOT IN 
           (select `time` from ( 
                               SELECT `time` FROM `server_week` 
                                WHERE `weekly` = 0 
                                ORDER BY `time` DESC 
                                LIMIT 10) t )
```

Comment: No I haven't, I'm just asking judging from the error message. Doesn't your query use `LIMIT` and `IN`, that _"This version of MySQL doesn't yet support"_?

Comment: it will not say this error i said :) , its in subquery not like yours , yours is wrong mysql doent support directly limit.

Comment: It's not _my_ query. I'm not the OP... Just passing by and saw your answer, made me wonder and asked for an explanation, since _this_ never happened to me. I'd really like to see an explanation, but if you won't provide one, it's just as good, I'll just redirect my search elsewhere :)

Comment: look this answer , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142097/mysql-delete-statement-with-limit

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271396/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-table-in-mysql

Comment: This still doesn't work  ; #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: It would not hurt to put some explanation as to why there is an error and why your answer would work. There are some people who are not just *after* the solution but also the reason behind it. :)

Comment: @GellieAnn it looks like in this case, you cant use IN directly with a subquery that utilizes a LIMIT. So, the workaround is to encapsulate them in yet another subquery to 'fool' the MySQL.

Comment: @cipley I see, so the error is because of `LIMIT`. Thanks. It can't update itself by referencing itself. Perhaps it needed the encapsulation to make it look like it is a different table.