# Removing all rows with specific value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table named contacts

```
       id   name  value
        1    a      x 
        2    b      c
        3    c      x
        4    d      x
        5    e      x
```

How I want to delete the rows that contain value of x ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack overflow. It seems like this might be a homework question. We don't mind helping with homework, but we do need to see a little bit of what you've tried. At the moment, the question is very much "please do this for me". A little bit of effort goes a long way :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete duplicate rows from a table in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271396/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-table-in-mysql)

Comment: FYI it took 3 seconds to find a duplicate question by almost the same name... did you even bother to search for it?

Comment: Thanks guys for the info and help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple SQL query will do.

```
DELETE * FROM contacts WHERE value='x'
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with duplicate data - just deletes every row with `x` in the value column

Comment: @MrShaa It might solve your immediate problem but please be aware that this **does not remove duplicates**. If you're happy with that, I suggest marking Gwiddle's answer as correct and editing your question to be something like "Removing all rows with specific value in MySQL" as it could be confusing for future users/searchers.

Comment: Okay, thanks I have done with editing. Thanks for the answer and guide.