# How removing duplicate rows Group two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (babynames) in my database which has duplicate records that I want to delete.

Ex Records in My Table

```
id category_id  baby_name   url_role    
1      6        karthik     karthik    
2      7        kalaivanan  kalaivanan    
3      4        arun        arun    
4      6        vijayakumar vijayakumar    
5      6        karthik     karthik    
6      6        karthik     karthik    
7      4        karthik     karthik
9      6        vijayakumar vijayakumar    
8      4        karthik     karthik
```

I Need Result

```
id category_id  baby_name   url_role    
1      6        karthik     karthik    
2      7        kalaivanan  kalaivanan    
3      4        arun        arun    
4      6        vijayakumar vijayakumar    
7      4        karthik     karthik
```

I Need to remove Duplicate Records Found in Same Category with same baby_name. I don't want to create a new table with distinct entries for this. I Need to delete duplicate entries from the existing table without the creation of any new table.

```
DELETE FROM babynames 
    WHERE id NOT IN 
      (   SELECT MIN(id)  
            FROM babynames 
        GROUP BY baby_name,category_id
      )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to delete duplicate rows from a table in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271396/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you should use a `JOIN`:

```
DELETE b
    FROM babynames b LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT baby_name, category_id, MIN(id) as min_id
          FROM babynames 
          GROUP BY baby_name,category_id
         ) bb
         ON bb.min_id = b.id
    WHERE bb.min_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EXISTS` clause, taking care to wrap the internal `FROM` into a subquery to avoid the dreaded

> You can't specify target table 'x' for update in FROM clause

error:

```
DELETE b
FROM babynames b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM (SELECT * FROM babynames) b1 
              WHERE b1.category_id = b.category_id
                AND b1.baby_name = b.baby_name
                AND b1.id < b.id)
```

Output:

```
id  category_id     baby_name       url_role
1   6               karthik         karthik
2   7               kalaivanan      kalaivanan
3   4               arun            arun
4   6               vijayakumar     vijayakumar
7   4               karthik         karthik
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=82c9c1a3bc84252b843b958362a14ada)

Answer (score 0):

To delete duplicate records from table you can do like below

```
delete from names 
where id not in 
(
select min(id)
from names 
group by category_id,baby_name,url_role 

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please Try this

```
 DELETE FROM babynames 
   WHERE id   IN 
                  (  
                  select id from (SELECT id ,  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY baby_name,category_id
                 ORDER BY  sale DESC  )rw sales_rank FROM babynames)t1 where rw>1
                  )
```